# Filtering with ~ operator not behaving as I would think

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 4000 row data frame which I am trying to filter. The condition is that if some string is contained in two columns of the same row, then filter it out, i.e. remove it.

For that I am using this:

```
data = data[
    (~data["col1"].str.contains("mystring"))
    & (~data["col2"].str.contains("mystring"))
]
```

This returns a reduced data frame with roughly 1800 rows left. However, if I use the `|` operator (or) instead of `&` I actually get fewer rows removed. That seems counterintuitive to me, since I would argue that with the `|` I would at least remove the same amount as with `&`.

But, if I remove the `~` operator, then yes, with `&` the returned list has fewer rows than with `|` - as I would imagine. So my guess is I may not use the `~` operator correctly here ? But I am not aware of my possible error here. So what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your logic is wrong – don't you mean

```
data = data[
    ~(
        data["col1"].str.contains("mystring")
        & data["col2"].str.contains("mystring")
    )
]
```

i.e. you'd pick the subset of rows that do have the same string in both columns, then invert it to get the subset of rows that *don't* match that criteria.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Just need to put it in the same parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

The boolean logic of negation is as follows:

```
~ (A & B)  is equivalent to (~ A | ~ B)
```

So, you can either write it with one `~` and one `&` or 2 `~` and one `|`, as follows:

```
data = data[
    (~data["col1"].str.contains("mystring"))
    | (~data["col2"].str.contains("mystring"))
]
```

or,

```
data = data[
    ~(data["col1"].str.contains("mystring")
      & data["col2"].str.contains("mystring"))
]
```

Comment: Wait... this is called boolean logic of negation, not De Morgan rule?

Comment: @Daweo Just a laymen term for ease of understanding.